'This database does not allow for DDL/DML' error in Apache superset
Running the following query in Apache superset on a Clickhouse DB
select top 2 storage_name
from proxy_space;

leads to error:

DB engine Error This database does not allow for DDL/DML, and the
query could not be parsed to confirm it is a read-only query. Please
contact your administrator for more assistance.

Running it without top 2 doesn't cause the error:
select storage_name
from proxy_space;

Why does superset consider it as a DDL/DML query? Is it a bug? Clickhouse driver is installed in superset.

Which dbms are you connected to? Does Apache superset know that? (top 2 is a product specific syntax.)

@jarlh Sorry, I've forgotten to mention this in the question. It's Clickhouse

Does it reproduce without superset? what is the database engine you used underneath?

@jsc0218 No, the first query executes successfully in a DB Explorer for example DBeaver.

@ka3ak could you check /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log  on clickhouse-sefver after query execution failure and share a full error message and stack trace from this log?

Does Clickhouse really support the MS SQL Server style top 2? I'd try  LIMIT 2 at the end instead.

@jarlh The official documentation doesn't mention 'top'. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select It may be the cause of the error. I'll use 'limit' instead. However it's still interesting why the first query works in DBeaver. superset must be using a different JDBC driver for Clickhouse.
